# i18next formatter with commas in format string

Tags: reactjs, localization, i18next

I'm trying to create a custom formatter for `i18next` in React that can handle receiving custom date formats in the localization files as options to the format function. Unfortunately there are no complex examples for custom formatters ([docs](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting#adding-custom-format-function)), such as passing multiple options or how to escape commas within the default format. As such, using a comma in the format function options is unfortunately considered to be another formatter, since that string is split with `,` by default. While this can be changed using the `formatSeparator` option, other good options are already taken. For example, `:` is used for separating format option keys and values; `;` is used for separating multiple format option pairs; `,` is used for separating multiple formatters.

Is there any other way to make this work *other* than changing the `formatSeparator` (maybe to something like `|`, which likely wouldn't be used in any format string options...)? Changing this separator feels like it could cause issues for other devs who may not be aware of the change, particularly as a invalid separator can cause parsing to fail! Where is `formatSeparator` all used? Is it *only* used to separate multiple formats (which I rarely use)?

```yaml
validations:
  date:
    # This improperly truncates the format due to ',' character..., which is thought
    #   to be indicate another formatter (split out in first pass of interpolation).
    min: "{{path}} must be after {{min, date(format: 'MMM DD, YYYY')}}"
```

```
i18n.services.formatter.add("date", (value, lng, options) => {
  return dayjs(value).format(options.format);
});
```

> **NOTE:** There was another way to do this in legacy `i18next` with the `interpolation.format` function, but creating custom formatters seems to be the recommended way forward.